# Why do only lattice vibrations contribute to the specific heat?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, born-oppenheimer-approximation

I would like to justify, that I can write the free energy of a real material (many-body system) at ambient conditions as
$$
F(T) = E_0^{\text{e}} + F^\text{v}(T)
$$
where $E_0^{\text{e}}$ is the ground state energy of the electronic Hamiltonian (assuming frozen nuclei) and $F^\text{v}(T)$ is the free energy of the nucleus vibrations. This is a common approach in ab-initio materials physics and leads to very good results, compared to experiment (see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6290)).

For metals, there is a simple way to justify this. One usually derives the specific heat by using the free electron model, and finds that the specific heat of the electrons is negligible compared to the specific heat of the phonons (like [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_heat_capacity)). Thus the electron contribution to the free energy can be approximated by a constant, $E_0^{\text{elec}}$. But this is only true for free electrons, which are a good approximation for metals. For insulators, I can't find any justification that the electron contribution is also negligible. This is unsatisfactory.

So, here is my try to justify the assumption, that only the lattice vibrations contribute to the free energy:

Lets assume that the energy eigenvalues $E_n$ of the full many-body Hamiltonian (including electrons and nuclei),
$$
H \psi_n = E_n \psi_n
$$
can be decomposed into the movement of the electrons, $E_n^\text{e}$, and the vibrations of the nuclei $E_n^\text{v}$,
$$
E_n = E_n^\text{e} + E_n^\text{v}
$$
This is justified by the Born-Oppenheimer approximation and we neglect higher order effects like rotations or electron-phonon interactions. I can then write the partition function as
$$
Z(T) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \text e^{-\beta E_n} = \text e^{-\beta E_0^\text{e} } \sum_{n=0}^\infty \text e^{-\beta (E_n- E_0^\text{e})}
$$
where I simply factored out the electron ground state energy, $E_0^\text{e}$. I can rewrite the exponent
$$
E_n- E_0^\text{e} = E_n^\text{e} + E_n^\text{v} - E_0^\text{e} = \Delta E_n^\text{e} + E_n^\text{v}
$$
in terms of the electronic excitations energies $\Delta E_n^\text{e} = E_n^\text{e} - E_0^\text{e}$. The free energy can always be written as
$$
F(T) = -\frac 1 \beta \ln Z(T)
$$
and I find
$$
F(T) = E_0^\text{e} - \frac 1 \beta \ln \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \text e^{-\beta (\Delta E_n^\text{e} + E_n^\text{v})} \right) \;.
$$
This looks close to what I want to have, but I need to show that the second term, containing $\Delta E_n^\text{e}$, can be approximated, neglecting $\Delta E_n^\text{e}$.

EDIT: adapted the question to *By Symmetrie*'s comment.

Comment: My hand waving approach would be that if you are in an insulator then exciting an electron takes an energy of at least $E_{gap}$. If $T \ll E_{gap}$ (and if this is not true you are in a semiconductor rather than an insulator) then the electronic degrees of freedom are exponentially  suppressed and so should not contribute to the free energy other than a constant. In other words if you are happy to neglect the temperature dependence for the electron free energy in a metal, then you should *definitely* be happy to neglect it in an insulator, where the electrons essentially can't move anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am wondering how I could formulate that in the equations, since in my version everything is surpressed, when $k_B T << \Delta E_n^\text{e}$.

Comment: I think one could do it, when we introduce two independent indices for the electronic and the phononic contributio to the energy (which should be allowed due to Born Oppenheimer). So I could write for the total energy spectrum $E_n = E_{n_1}^\text{e} + E_{n_2}^\text{v}$ where $n=(n_1,n_2)$ is a compound index. Then the sum in the partition function has two independent indices and the decay of $\text{exp}(-\beta \Delta E_{n_1}^\text{e})$ does not surpress everything but just the electronic part. The sum over $n_2$ then remains, containing all the phononic contributions.